# multiple upload not saved to database

Tags: php, mysql

```
var a=0;
function _add_more() {
    var txt = "<br><input type=\"file\" name=\"item_file[]\"><br><input type=\"text\" name=\"text"+a+"\">";
    document.getElementById("dvFile").innerHTML += txt;
    alert(a);
    a=a+1;
}
```

I am using multiple file upload and with multiple titles. I am not able to save text in database for title. Can you please tell the correct syntax `$_POST["text"]`, where should i put a that i am increementing.

```
$insert=mysql_query("insert into image_upload set title='".$_POST["text"]."', image='".$filen."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What John Boker said is true.
But you will need to loop through them to insert them into the database.
An easy way would be to make `name=\"text"+a+"\"`, `name=\"text[]\"` (like your file upload element),
So then you would have an array of titles.

So in PHP:
`foreach($_POST["text"] as $title){`
`$insert=mysql_query("insert into image_upload set title='".$title."', image='".$filen."'") or die(mysql_error());`
`}`

Also why not use `'`s in your JavaScript instead of escaping the `"`s?

You could probably just loop through your titles while you are looping through your uploaded files.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST["text"]` is not defined, the names of the fields are `$_POST["text0"]`,  `$_POST["text1"]`,  `$_POST["text2"]`, ... one for each input you have.

you should add `a` to a hidden field then you'll know the number of inputs you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same strategy for your naming your title fields as you did for you file upload fields:

```
var txt = "<br><input type=\"file\" name=\"item_file[]\"><br><input type=\"text\" name=\"text[]"\">";
```

Notice I name them all `text[]`. Now in PHP I have the variable `$_POST['text']`, which is of itself an array containing all the titles.

To access the files as well as the titles in PHP you can do:

```
for($i=0; $i<length($_FILES['item_file']); $i++) {
    print $_FILES['item_file'][$i]['name'] +"<br>";
    print $_POST['text'][$i] + "<br>";
}
```

Also, I am obliged to inform you that performing mysql queries without proper validation of your input is bound to get you hacked. Please consider using:

```
$insert=mysql_query("insert into image_upload set title='". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["text"]) ."', image='". mysql_real_escape_string($filen) ."'") or die(mysql_error());
```